# DotNetCore: cross platform version of GetInvalidFileNameChars?

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, operating-system, .net-core

I'm building a .Net Core 2.0 console application that will run on both Windows and Ubuntu systems. I have a string that needs to be converted into a safe file name. Currently I'm using the following code to achieve this:

`var safeName = string.Join("-", name.Split(Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()));`

It works, but it will produce different results on different operating system as Linux allows characters that Windows will not allow. I like a solution that produces the same result on all of the systems.

Is there a **cross platform** version of `GetInvalidFileNameChars` that will return characters for all platforms?

Comment: You can manullay replace any none alpha-numeric charcters with "-". It is a conservatice but a safe way.

Comment: So instead of black-listing I could use white-listing?

Comment: Alhpa-numeric charcters are valid on both Windows and Linux. Using only these characters is valid on both platforms.

Comment: It's safe to also include minus underscore, periods, space and a few others. Linux will allow everything except slash and NUL -- plus colon should be avoided. Windows is the limiter. Exclude the Windows path and stream separators (slash, backslash, and colon), wildcard characters (asterisk, question mark, less than, greater than, and double quote), ASCII control characters (0-31), and pipe (|). Also don't end a filename with a period or space because Windows will strip it off. And don't use reserved DOS device names: NUL, CON, CONIN$, CONOUT$, AUX, PRN, COM1-COM9, and LPT1-LPT9.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think there is a "cross-platform" version in the BCL, but you can easily make one yourself by copying the [Windows version of GetInvalidFileNameChars](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/IO/Path.Windows.cs), because the [Unix version](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/25ea6c44cf3140cc9bfbaaff7f01ad2a27414f8e/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/IO/Path.Unix.cs) is just a subset of these and they're not likely to change often:

```
        public static char[] GetInvalidFileNameChars() => new char[]
        {
            '\"', '<', '>', '|', '\0',
            (char)1, (char)2, (char)3, (char)4, (char)5, (char)6, (char)7, (char)8, (char)9, (char)10,
            (char)11, (char)12, (char)13, (char)14, (char)15, (char)16, (char)17, (char)18, (char)19, (char)20,
            (char)21, (char)22, (char)23, (char)24, (char)25, (char)26, (char)27, (char)28, (char)29, (char)30,
            (char)31, ':', '*', '?', '\\', '/'
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the following will will work:

```
var invalidCharStr =

    //printable chars linux/unix
    "/" +

    //unprintable chars linux/unix
    Convert.ToChar(0) +

    //printable chars Windows
    @"><:""/\|?*" +

    //unprintable chars Windows: 0-31
    new string(Enumerable.Range(0, 32).Select(Convert.ToChar).ToArray());
```

Have them as an array like:

```
var invalidChars = invalidCharStr.ToArray();
```